# Modal and tenses: if only+before, would have+by now

Tags: grammar, tense, modal-verbs

Let's say you have regretted that you didn't read books before, as a result you have a very minimal understanding about life at your present state. And you say:

> **If only** I had read many books **before**, I **would** have learned more about life **by now**

*a regret in the past that has a result in the present.

Is this a correct usage of **modal verbs**?

Comment: Yes, but the sentence is clumsy. "If only I had read many books before" does not sound natural. I suggest "I didn't read many books, but if I had, I would have learned more about life by now".

Comment: Yes, it's fine. And I actually find it to sound quite natural—especially if said in a reflective or regretful tone of voice.

Comment: @WeatherVane - or, _"If only I had read more books...”_